# Importing react with webpack Error: Cannot resolve module 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm getting an error `Error: Cannot resolve module 'react'` (and react-dom) with webpack. This has to be the hardest project setup I've had to deal with and I'm really not sure why its not working. I've also checked for similar issues on so, and can't seem to find a solution.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './static/js/base/base.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/static/scripts',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**base.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  // ...
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    [
      // Functions & Event Handlers declaration
    ].forEach(method => { this[method] = this[method].bind(this); });

    this.state = {
      hello: 'Hello World!',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div href="#" class="header item">
          WINPMP Login
        </div>
        <div class="right menu">
          <a class="ui primary button item">Students</a>
          <a class="ui button item">Teachers</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Navigation/>, document.getElementById('nav'));
```

I've run `npm install`, everything is there. Why won't it import properly? How can I make this work?

And my package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
```

Comment: show your `package.json`

Comment: You don't use `html-webpack-plugin`?

Comment: On a side note, this is why the React team have created a tool to help with all this initial setup. They blogged about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html ; you could always set up a project with it and then `eject` the auto-config part of it, and compare their config with your own. (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html#no-lock-in)

Comment: It's possible you may need a .babelrc file for your presets

Comment: @mklimek new to webpack. forgive my noobness

Comment: @John i'd love to go forward with creating a new project. but i'm basically adding react to a django/python project :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a .babelrc file in your project root which looks like this:

```
{
  presets: [
    "es2015", "react"
  ]
}
```

and pull out the 'query' field from your webpack config 'loader'

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'sockjs-client'`

Comment: Hmm.. that's odd.. I haven't heard of that one but apparently it's used by webpack-dev-server; not really sure why it wouldn't be found.. maybe reinstall webpack-dev-server? or delete node_modules and re-run `npm i` ?

Comment: hmmm yeah that didn't seem to cut it. i will however mark your answer as correct since it did help my progression. so thank you :D